# How to use Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction to define GROUP_CONCAT with SEPARATOR option

Tags: ruby, arel

I defined a named Arel function for MariaDB's GROUP_CONCAT

```
ta = Arel::Table.new 'authors'

Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new( 'GROUP_CONCAT',  [ta[:name]] ).to_sql
```

This generates:

```
"GROUP_CONCAT(`authors`.`name`)"
```

I like however to define the separator option to generate the following output:

```
"GROUP_CONCAT(`authors`.`name` SEPARATOR '|' )"
```

I tried a number of approaches, for example

```
Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new( 'GROUP_CONCAT',  [ ta[:name]], "SEPERATOR |"  ).to_sql
```

Doesn't work since it creates the following SQL snippet:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(`authors`.`name`) AS SEPERATOR '|'
```

How do I need to specify the parameters for the desired output?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you nearly had it. All of the arguments go into the array (second argument). AFAIK, Arel has always been considered a private API, so documentation is pretty sparse.

(https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/354f1c28e81d9846fb9e5346fcca50cf303c12c1/activerecord/lib/arel/nodes/named_function.rb)

```rb
Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('GROUP_CONCAT', [ta[:name], Arel.sql("SEPARATOR '|'")]).to_sql
```

Comment: Code only answers are generally considered low quality. Could you add an explanation to your answer.

Comment: Please explain your answer and explain why it works the way OP need it to work.

Comment: Many thanks @firien. Of course, the SQL function parameters all needed passing on in one argument since the thrird parameter is the alias as per definition. SUppose you could add that to your answer  `Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction#new(name, expr, aliaz = nil)`